# Datatables and Moment

Tags: jquery, datatables, momentjs

I am using a datatable and adding the sort on the datetime column.
When the datetime is formatted like this date **01/01/2021 10:11:20 AM** the sorting works but when its formatted like this  **01/01/2021 10:11:20AM** it does not

I am using the moment.js a swell

Comment: You can take a look at the approach shown here: [DataTables - How to sort by date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68163742/12567365). In your case, the date format for moment.js will be `DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss a` or `DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ssa` depending on whether you have a space between the seconds (`ss`) value and the AM/PM (`a`) value.

Comment: The above comment assumes you **do not** have both formats mixed in the same column. You should provide a [mre] with some code and sample data if the above approach does not help. There are also many other similar questions and answers here on SO for you to research.